# Upload large file to Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am quite new to setup a MS Access data base. Just wondering whether there is a way to upload a coma delimited file with more than 1.5 million rows and ignore the first 3 lines (file header) and the last row (footer).
The header for the content of this file is at the 4th row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i worked it out myself.
the header and the footer are having different number of columns.
I used line input statement to check each line of the my text file.
Here is my code:

```
Sub FileUpload_CMP_Funding()

Dim sFile, sText As String
Dim dText As Variant
Dim db As Database
Dim rst As Recordset2
Dim i As Long

sFile = "C:\NotBackedUp\testfile\CMPFUNding.out"
Open sFile For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, sText
        dText = Empty
        dText = Split(vText(i), ",")
        'My main content has 24 columns 
        If UBound(dText) - LBound(dText) + 1 = 24 Then
            If dText(0) <> "Product ID" Then 'skip the header row at the 4th rows

                Set db = CurrentDb
                Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblCMP_Funding", dbOpenDynaset)
                rst.AddNew
                rst!ProductID = Trim(Replace(dText(0), """", ""))
                rst!FundID = Trim(Replace(dText(1), """", ""))
                ""
                'Update whatever field is required to be updated
                rst.Update
                Set db = Nothing
                Set rst = Nothing
            End If
        End If
Loop
Close #1

End Sub
```

Hope it helps anyone who have same requirement